# Raspbian sound problems

Tags: audio, hdmi

I'm having problems getting sound to work on my RPi. I'm running raspbian, and I want the sound to play over HDMI.

I've tried `omxplayer -o hdmi path/to/myfile.mp3` with the HDMI cable, and `omxplayer path/to/myfile.mp3` over analogue. None of them works.

The system is updated and upgraded to the latest packages, I've also done `modprobe snd_bcm2835` which as I understand enables audio?

Is sound supposed to work out of the box or do I have to get any packages or something?

Comment: Try running `amixer cset numid=3 2`, which should force audio be go through HDMI.

Answer (score 2):

audio via HDMI should work out-of-the-box, however there are some issues with your HDMI receiver (e.g. TV which raspberry pi is connected to)

see my struggle on this topic here:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57984&p=442479#p442479

gerenally check if hdmi_drive=2 or even better set hdmi to [safe mode](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig)

Comment: I edited /boot/config.txt and uncommented both hdmi_drive=2 and hdmi_safe=1 but still no sound.

Comment: did you reboot after that?